# Maurice Fréchet's Generalités sur les probabilités

Tags: probability, book-recommendation

I know that in this forum there are many serious mathematics students interested in probability (that is, rigorous probability) and its origins. That is just why I dared to post this non-technical question. Does anyone know where do I can purchase --or download-- Maurice Fréchet's $Generalités$ $sur$ $les$ $probabilités$. $Variables$ $aleatoires$? Apparently the book was published by Gauthier-Villars in 1937; I already searched in Éditions Jacques Gabay but they do not sell it; I also tried Numdam, but nope.

Any idea --besides a well-known library-- where I can get this important job of Mr. Maurice Fréchet? (I admit there may be several important libraries where I could get this book from, but I live in Mexico City, and that completely discards that unfeasible option.)

Thanks.

Comment: I'd be interested in an english translation of it.

Comment: It seems to be available. Look at http://www.biblio.com/book/generalites-probabilites-variables-aleatoires-premier-livre/d/323196318

Comment: Regarding purchasing, see [here](http://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=15631284696&searchurl=tn=les%20probabilites&an=frechet%20maurice).